# PHP - Looping through indexed JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have parsed and looped through JSON plenty of times. I have seemed to hit a wall with something I have not done before and I have been unable to find an answer and hopefully I am referencing this correctly. I have been really struggling with this.

With the code example below I can parse it and assign a varible to an object and get its value like so.

```
$result = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($result);

echo $result['response'][0]['report']['type'];
```

This is where the problem comes in and it starts with the array index and I am hoping I am referring to this correctly. Basically it is the [0] from above. I have never looped through something like that before and my research has come up empty.  Normally I would do it like this.

```
$json = '{"success":true,"error":null,"response":[{"id":"59c30487db6be86b7f8b465a","loc":{"long":-90.45,"lat":43.43},"report":{"code":"R","type":"heavy rain","name":"Gillingham","detail":{"text":1,"rainIN":1,"rainMM":25.4},"reporter":"co-op observer","comments":"","timestamp":1505952240,"cat":"rain","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T19:04:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T19:04:00-05:00","wfo":"arx"},"place":{"name":"gillingham","state":"wi","county":"richland","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c302a9db6be82a758b46e8","loc":{"long":-90.93,"lat":43.32},"report":{"code":"R","type":"heavy rain","name":"Mount Sterling","detail":{"text":2.25,"rainIN":2.25,"rainMM":57.15},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"","timestamp":1505951760,"cat":"rain","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T18:56:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T18:56:00-05:00","wfo":"arx"},"place":{"name":"mount sterling","state":"wi","county":"crawford","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c30106db6be8146c8b4661","loc":{"long":-89.53,"lat":44.45},"report":{"code":"R","type":"heavy rain","name":"Plover","detail":{"text":1.05,"rainIN":1.05,"rainMM":26.67},"reporter":"co-op observer","comments":"One hour total rainfall. also measured a 49 mph wind gust at 511 pm. no hail.","timestamp":1505950800,"cat":"rain","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T18:40:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T18:40:00-05:00","wfo":"grb"},"place":{"name":"plover","state":"wi","county":"portage","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c3080adb6be8d5138b4654","loc":{"long":-89.33,"lat":44.37},"report":{"code":"H","type":"hail","name":"4 mi NNW Blaine","detail":{"text":0.88,"hailIN":0.88,"hailMM":22.35},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"Nickel size hail and heavy rain. 3.25 to 3.49 inches in the past 2 hours.","timestamp":1505950680,"cat":"hail","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T18:38:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T18:38:00-05:00","wfo":"grb"},"place":{"name":"blaine","state":"wi","county":"portage","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c30106db6be8146c8b4660","loc":{"long":-90.93,"lat":43.32},"report":{"code":"H","type":"hail","name":"Mount Sterling","detail":{"text":0.75,"hailIN":0.75,"hailMM":19.05},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"Hail ranged from 1\/2 to 3\/4 inch.","timestamp":1505950200,"cat":"hail","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T18:30:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T18:30:00-05:00","wfo":"arx"},"place":{"name":"mount sterling","state":"wi","county":"crawford","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c2fd80db6be844598b466d","loc":{"long":-89.77,"lat":44.21},"report":{"code":"R","type":"heavy rain","name":"6 mi ESE New Rome","detail":{"text":4,"rainIN":4,"rainMM":101.6},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"","timestamp":1505949840,"cat":"rain","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T18:24:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T18:24:00-05:00","wfo":"arx"},"place":{"name":"rome","state":"wi","county":"adams","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c2f678db6be898338b4673","loc":{"long":-89.3,"lat":44.46},"report":{"code":"H","type":"hail","name":"Amherst Junction","detail":{"text":1,"hailIN":1,"hailMM":25.4},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"","timestamp":1505948340,"cat":"hail","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T17:59:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T17:59:00-05:00","wfo":"grb"},"place":{"name":"amherst junction","state":"wi","county":"portage","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c2f2f6db6be8a2208b4672","loc":{"long":-89.4,"lat":44.26},"report":{"code":"H","type":"hail","name":"Almond","detail":{"text":2,"hailIN":2,"hailMM":50.8},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"Report via social media","timestamp":1505948160,"cat":"hail","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T17:56:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T17:56:00-05:00","wfo":"grb"},"place":{"name":"almond","state":"wi","county":"portage","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}}]}';
    $result = json_decode($json, true);
    print_r($result);    

    foreach($result as report) {

        $type = $report['report']['type'];

     echo $type;
    }
```

That would usually work in most cases but since this has the [0] and increases with each new entry I am not sure how to loop through that as my entry point is different that what I have dealt with before and have been unable to find any working examples for something like this. Not to mention I am not sure how to working ['response'] into the loop ether with those index keys.

Here is a decode example of the array and what I am working with.

```
Array ( [success] => 1 [error] => [response] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 59c30487db6be86b7f8b465a [loc] => Array ( [long] => -90.45 [lat] => 43.43 ) [report] => Array ( [code] => R [type] => heavy rain [name] => Gillingham [detail] => Array ( [text] => 1 [rainIN] => 1 [rainMM] => 25.4 ) [reporter] => co-op observer [comments] => [timestamp] => 1505952240 [cat] => rain [dateTimeISO] => 2017-09-20T19:04:00-05:00 [datetime] => 2017-09-20T19:04:00-05:00 [wfo] => arx ) [place] => Array ( [name] => gillingham [state] => wi [county] => richland [country] => us ) [profile] => Array ( [tz] => America/Chicago ) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 59c302a9db6be82a758b46e8 [loc] => Array ( [long] => -90.93 [lat] => 43.32 ) [report] => Array ( [code] => R [type] => heavy rain [name] => Mount Sterling [detail] => Array ( [text] => 2.25 [rainIN] => 2.25 [rainMM] => 57.15 ) [reporter] => trained spotter [comments] => [timestamp] => 1505951760 [cat] => rain [dateTimeISO] => 2017-09-20T18:56:00-05:00 [datetime] => 2017-09-20T18:56:00-05:00 [wfo] => arx ) [place] => Array ( [name] => mount sterling [state] => wi [county] => crawford [country] => us ) [profile] => Array ( [tz] => America/Chicago ) ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 59c30106db6be8146c8b4661 [loc] => Array ( [long] => -89.53 [lat] => 44.45 ) [report] => Array ( [code] => R [type] => heavy rain [name] => Plover [detail] => Array ( [text] => 1.05 [rainIN] => 1.05 [rainMM] => 26.67 ) [reporter] => co-op observer [comments] => One hour total rainfall. also measured a 49 mph wind gust at 511 pm. no hail. [timestamp] => 1505950800 [cat] => rain [dateTimeISO] => 2017-09-20T18:40:00-05:00 [datetime] => 2017-09-20T18:40:00-05:00 [wfo] => grb ) [place] => Array ( [name] => plover [state] => wi [county] => portage [country] => us ) [profile] => Array ( [tz] => America/Chicago ) ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 59c3080adb6be8d5138b4654 [loc] => Array ( [long] => -89.33 [lat] => 44.37 ) [report] => Array ( [code] => H [type] => hail [name] => 4 mi NNW Blaine [detail] => Array ( [text] => 0.88 [hailIN] => 0.88 [hailMM] => 22.35 ) [reporter] => trained spotter [comments] => Nickel size hail and heavy rain. 3.25 to 3.49 inches in the past 2 hours. [timestamp] => 1505950680 [cat] => hail [dateTimeISO] => 2017-09-20T18:38:00-05:00 [datetime] => 2017-09-20T18:38:00-05:00 [wfo] => grb ) [place] => Array ( [name] => blaine [state] => wi [county] => portage [country] => us ) [profile] => Array ( [tz] => America/Chicago ) ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 59c30106db6be8146c8b4660 [loc] => Array ( [long] => -90.93 [lat] => 43.32 ) [report] => Array ( [code] => H [type] => hail [name] => Mount Sterling [detail] => Array ( [text] => 0.75 [hailIN] => 0.75 [hailMM] => 19.05 ) [reporter] => trained spotter [comments] => Hail ranged from 1/2 to 3/4 inch. [timestamp] => 1505950200 [cat] => hail [dateTimeISO] => 2017-09-20T18:30:00-05:00 [datetime] => 2017-09-20T18:30:00-05:00 [wfo] => arx ) [place] => Array ( [name] => mount sterling [state] => wi [county] => crawford [country] => us ) [profile] => Array ( [tz] => America/Chicago ) ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 59c2fd80db6be844598b466d [loc] => Array ( [long] => -89.77 [lat] => 44.21 ) [report] => Array ( [code] => R [type] => heavy rain [name] => 6 mi ESE New Rome [detail] => Array ( [text] => 4 [rainIN] => 4 [rainMM] => 101.6 ) [reporter] => trained spotter [comments] => [timestamp] => 1505949840 [cat] => rain [dateTimeISO] => 2017-09-20T18:24:00-05:00 [datetime] => 2017-09-20T18:24:00-05:00 [wfo] => arx ) [place] => Array ( [name] => rome [state] => wi [county] => adams [country] => us ) [profile] => Array ( [tz] => America/Chicago ) ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 59c2f678db6be898338b4673 [loc] => Array ( [long] => -89.3 [lat] => 44.46 ) [report] => Array ( [code] => H [type] => hail [name] => Amherst Junction [detail] => Array ( [text] => 1 [hailIN] => 1 [hailMM] => 25.4 ) [reporter] => trained spotter [comments] => [timestamp] => 1505948340 [cat] => hail [dateTimeISO] => 2017-09-20T17:59:00-05:00 [datetime] => 2017-09-20T17:59:00-05:00 [wfo] => grb ) [place] => Array ( [name] => amherst junction [state] => wi [county] => portage [country] => us ) [profile] => Array ( [tz] => America/Chicago ) ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 59c2f2f6db6be8a2208b4672 [loc] => Array ( [long] => -89.4 [lat] => 44.26 ) [report] => Array ( [code] => H [type] => hail [name] => Almond [detail] => Array ( [text] => 2 [hailIN] => 2 [hailMM] => 50.8 ) [reporter] => trained spotter [comments] => Report via social media [timestamp] => 1505948160 [cat] => hail [dateTimeISO] => 2017-09-20T17:56:00-05:00 [datetime] => 2017-09-20T17:56:00-05:00 [wfo] => grb ) [place] => Array ( [name] => almond [state] => wi [county] => portage [country] => us ) [profile] => Array ( [tz] => America/Chicago ) ) ) )
```

How would I loop through this with the Index key [#] and if I am referring to this incorrectly feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use loop in `$result["response"]` as:

```
$json = '{"success":true,"error":null,"response":[{"id":"59c30487db6be86b7f8b465a","loc":{"long":-90.45,"lat":43.43},"report":{"code":"R","type":"heavy rain","name":"Gillingham","detail":{"text":1,"rainIN":1,"rainMM":25.4},"reporter":"co-op observer","comments":"","timestamp":1505952240,"cat":"rain","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T19:04:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T19:04:00-05:00","wfo":"arx"},"place":{"name":"gillingham","state":"wi","county":"richland","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c302a9db6be82a758b46e8","loc":{"long":-90.93,"lat":43.32},"report":{"code":"R","type":"heavy rain","name":"Mount Sterling","detail":{"text":2.25,"rainIN":2.25,"rainMM":57.15},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"","timestamp":1505951760,"cat":"rain","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T18:56:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T18:56:00-05:00","wfo":"arx"},"place":{"name":"mount sterling","state":"wi","county":"crawford","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c30106db6be8146c8b4661","loc":{"long":-89.53,"lat":44.45},"report":{"code":"R","type":"heavy rain","name":"Plover","detail":{"text":1.05,"rainIN":1.05,"rainMM":26.67},"reporter":"co-op observer","comments":"One hour total rainfall. also measured a 49 mph wind gust at 511 pm. no hail.","timestamp":1505950800,"cat":"rain","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T18:40:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T18:40:00-05:00","wfo":"grb"},"place":{"name":"plover","state":"wi","county":"portage","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c3080adb6be8d5138b4654","loc":{"long":-89.33,"lat":44.37},"report":{"code":"H","type":"hail","name":"4 mi NNW Blaine","detail":{"text":0.88,"hailIN":0.88,"hailMM":22.35},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"Nickel size hail and heavy rain. 3.25 to 3.49 inches in the past 2 hours.","timestamp":1505950680,"cat":"hail","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T18:38:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T18:38:00-05:00","wfo":"grb"},"place":{"name":"blaine","state":"wi","county":"portage","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c30106db6be8146c8b4660","loc":{"long":-90.93,"lat":43.32},"report":{"code":"H","type":"hail","name":"Mount Sterling","detail":{"text":0.75,"hailIN":0.75,"hailMM":19.05},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"Hail ranged from 1\/2 to 3\/4 inch.","timestamp":1505950200,"cat":"hail","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T18:30:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T18:30:00-05:00","wfo":"arx"},"place":{"name":"mount sterling","state":"wi","county":"crawford","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c2fd80db6be844598b466d","loc":{"long":-89.77,"lat":44.21},"report":{"code":"R","type":"heavy rain","name":"6 mi ESE New Rome","detail":{"text":4,"rainIN":4,"rainMM":101.6},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"","timestamp":1505949840,"cat":"rain","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T18:24:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T18:24:00-05:00","wfo":"arx"},"place":{"name":"rome","state":"wi","county":"adams","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c2f678db6be898338b4673","loc":{"long":-89.3,"lat":44.46},"report":{"code":"H","type":"hail","name":"Amherst Junction","detail":{"text":1,"hailIN":1,"hailMM":25.4},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"","timestamp":1505948340,"cat":"hail","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T17:59:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T17:59:00-05:00","wfo":"grb"},"place":{"name":"amherst junction","state":"wi","county":"portage","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c2f2f6db6be8a2208b4672","loc":{"long":-89.4,"lat":44.26},"report":{"code":"H","type":"hail","name":"Almond","detail":{"text":2,"hailIN":2,"hailMM":50.8},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"Report via social media","timestamp":1505948160,"cat":"hail","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-20T17:56:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-20T17:56:00-05:00","wfo":"grb"},"place":{"name":"almond","state":"wi","county":"portage","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}}]}';
$result = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($result["response"] as $report) {
    $type = $report['report']['type'];
    echo $type;
}
```

Check the result here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c7b55a67e649bdc8c35ec1ba8218747de1f8ac16

Comment: for your examples, you should use https://3v4l.org/ because it's faster, cleaner, and supports https

Comment: Wow I figured it was something easy. It was the one thing I didn't try. I did try it like this `$result->response` didn't even think to do it that other way. Works great now.

Comment: @Jeff Puckett: Thank you for your suggestion. I will use 3v4l.org in the future posts.
DFWStormForce: Cuz it's an array, not an object so we need [] to access.